# Method from a data bind (DevExpress Report)

Tags: asp.net-core, devexpress

I am creating a label report for bank check printing. I would like to know which component of the toolbox I can use to create a method (which I already have) to convert the numeric value to value in full.
Follow the design screen.

[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEGxC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could place an XRLabel control onto the report for the text value and handle its [BeforePrint](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.BeforePrint.event) event to invoke your method for converting the numeric value to text.